# Marking author's own work when citing them

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib

There is a requirement for my PhD thesis: all my own works shall be marked with * when cited, like this:

```
as I noted in [3*], something something
```

All other works shall be cited as usual. In bibliography my works and other authors' works will be in the same list, without any special marks, so there'll be no problem here.

I assume you could change closing with `\bibpunct`, but that would change output globally, if I understand correctly.

Ideally, I would like to have some `\citemy` command which would format citing with a star. I will use it to cite my own works, and `\cite` for all other articles.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `biblatex` has a `\DeclareCiteCommand` macro, but I see you’re using `natbib`.

Comment: daleif's answer solved my problem, so I'm quite content. But if you present `biblatex` solution, I'd be happy to upvote it too after testing. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this, i'd recomment you make `\mycite` more advanced such that you get the extra options as well (`xparse` will help)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
% simple, does not support the normal \cite options
\newcommand\mycite[1]{%
  % groups does not help
  \bibpunct{[}{*]}{,}{n}{}{,}%
  \cite{#1}%
  \bibpunct{[}{]}{,}{n}{}{,}%
}
\begin{document}

\mycite{me}
\cite{other}

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem[Me(2014)]{me} By Me, 2014.
\bibitem[Other(2010)]{other}  Other guy, 2010.
\end{thebibliography}


\end{document}
```

Comment: You would be surpirsed, but I've tried this on my own, and it didn't work. May be I've made a mistake somewhere, idk. Anyway, this time it **did** work, thank you. :)